# Why is `is_open()` non-const?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have a function similar to below which is const and needs to check that a file stream is open prior to continuing:

```
bool MyClass::checkSomeStuff() const
{
    // Where outputFile_ is a std::ofstream
    if ( ! outputFile_.is_open() )
    {
        throw std::runtime_error( "Output file not open." );
    }

    // ... do more stuff
```

However, It seems I can't do this as `is_open()` is declared as:

```
bool is_open ( );
```

(i.e. non-const)

To me it seems a bit odd that a function like this - which is clearly a pure accessor - should be non-const. Is there a logic behind it which makes sense?

Comment: what could you do with a `const` stream?

Comment: Good discussion on this very subject here: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2004-08/msg00105.html

Comment: @Nim: Probably not much, but that's not the point. The point is that the *operation* of checking whether the stream is open or not should not logically change it - it's just a check. My `checkSomeStuff` function is, and should be, const - it's an accessor. I would not want it to be non-const purely because `is_open()` is non-const - that doesn't seem right.

Comment: You can use `outputFile.rdbuf()->is_open()` instead if your compiler doesn't implement library DR 365

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is in fact `const` in C++11. The C++03 version is an unfortunate error.

Answer (score 13):

This is a known discrepancy in the standard library. You can find  more information about it over here:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#365

Answer (score -1):

- Let's see on CPPReference, what is `is_open()` for:

> The stream is associated with a file if either a previous call to
>   member open succeeded or if the object was successfully constructed
>   using the parameterized constructor, and close has not been called
>   since.

So, use it immediately after `open()` / `close()`. That is why the old `is_open()` non-const. ;)

- Use `bool good() const` instead.

Comment: Wait... how does it being used after `open()` and `close()` mean it should be non-`const`?

Comment: @devidark: Unfortunately `good()` is not a feasible substitute here as it fails to highlight if (a) the file has not yet been opened or (b) it has been opened and closed successfully.

Comment: @quasiverse: Because `open()`/`close()` are modify stream's state. @Component 10: Agree with you. But if your code is in consitence, you're get enough with `bool good() const`. ;)

Comment: @devidark Yes but `is_open()` doesn't modify the stream's state...(?)

Comment: @quasiverse: If old `is_open()` is not `const`, then it doesn't get that guarantee. Isn't it?